# How to subtract the next value from the previous value in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to subtract the previous value from the next value in a list and finally add the out put into a dictionary.

Example:

```
# Original List
l= [1, 10, 25, 35, 55, 100]
# Expected Out put
nl = [9, 15, 10, 20, 45]
# another list
lst = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
# final result
result = [{'col1': 9}, {'col2': 15}, {'col3': 10}, {'col4': 20}, {'col5': 45}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Comment: You'll use `zip` as stated in link to process both lists simultaneously, but instead of two lists you'll have `l` and `l[1:]`

Comment: In one line: `nl = [y-x for x,y in zip(l, l[1:])]` The 'final result' is similar: `result = [{k:v} for k, v in zip(lst, nl)]

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. did not found the other post you mentioned earlier. @Two-Bit Alchemist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

```
l= [1, 10, 25, 35, 55, 100]
nl = [(n-l[i-1]) if i else n for i,n in enumerate(l)]
lst = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
final = dict(zip(lst, nl))
Out[460]: {'col1': 1, 'col2': 9, 'col3': 15, 'col4': 10, 'col5': 20}
```